# Spiner into RecyclerView item - kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, layout

i have problem with adding simple Spiner to RecyclerView item. I saw a lot of examples but i cannot add it to my project. All i want is the same Spiner with list of Strings in every item of RecyclerView. I have no problem with implement this without RecycylerView, but with it, i dont know where to pass Adapter for Spiner.

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```html
class MealPlanerAdapter(val mealList: MutableList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    val mealCalories = mutableListOf<Int>()




    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mealList.size

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_row, parent, false)

        mealList.forEach {
            mealCalories.add(100 / mealList.size)
        }


        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "CutPasteId", "ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {


        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.meal_name_text_view).text = "Meal name"
        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.calosies_slider_name_text_view).text = "Daily calories:  "

        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.calories_value_text_view).text = holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(
            R.id.calories_seek_bar
        ).progress.toString()+"%"
        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.protein_value_text_view).text = holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(
            R.id.protein_seek_bar
        ).progress.toString()+"%"
        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fat_value_text_view).text = holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(
            R.id.fat_seek_bar
        ).progress.toString()+"%"
        holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.carbs_value_text_view).text = holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(
            R.id.calories_seek_bar
        ).progress.toString()+"%"
        holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.calories_seek_bar).progress = mealCalories[position]

        var proteinValue: Int = 20
        var fatValue: Int = 25

        holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.calories_seek_bar).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
            SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(
                seekBar: SeekBar?,
                progress: Int,
                fromUser: Boolean
            ) {
                holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.calories_value_text_view).text =
                    "$progress%"
                println(position)
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

        })

        holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.protein_seek_bar).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
            SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.protein_value_text_view).text = "$progress%"
                proteinValue = progress
                holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.carbs_seek_bar).progress =
                    100 - proteinValue - fatValue
                holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.carbs_seek_bar).refreshDrawableState()

            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

        })

        holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.fat_seek_bar).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
            SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fat_value_text_view).text = "$progress%"
                fatValue = progress
                holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.carbs_seek_bar).progress =
                    100 - proteinValue - fatValue
                holder.view.findViewById<View>(R.id.carbs_seek_bar).refreshDrawableState()

            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

        })

        holder.view.findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.carbs_seek_bar).setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }


    }




}


class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {


   

}
```

Fragment:

```html
class MealPlanerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_meal_planer) {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private val mealList = mutableListOf<String>("1", "2", "3")
    private lateinit var mAdapter: MealPlanerAdapter
    private lateinit var mLinearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        mAdapter = MealPlanerAdapter(mealList)


    }

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId", "ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val inflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meal_planer, container, false)
        mLinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)


        mRecyclerView = inflater.findViewById(recycler_view_meal_planer)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = mLinearLayoutManager
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter





        return inflater
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

   
}
```

Comment: There is no spinner in your code

Comment: Yes, because i don't know how properly add it and i though someone will give me example based on my code or sth similar.